# Is it possible to use an Integer to call methods and arrays dynamically?

Tags: java, integer

For example:

3 methods exist

"map1method,

map2method,

map3mehtod"

and I want to call the right one depending on what the integer 'activemap' has currently stored in it.

I could do an If statement

"If (activemap == 1)

map1method;

elseif (activemap ==2)

..."

But is there a possible way of using the integer more efficiently?

Like a "map(activemap)method"

Also could I also call a specific array in a batch of them in the same fashion.

This is all in java by the way.

Comment: Please have a look chain of responsibility pattern. http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/chain-of-responsibility-pattern.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible via reflection but I would urge you to stay away from that approach. Why not have all three methods built into one? One option would be to use a `switch` statement to handle the various cases:

```
void mapMethod(int activemap) {
    switch (activemap) {
    case 1:
        // map1method
        break;
    case 2:
        // map2method
        break;
    case 3:
        // map3method
        break;
     default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Now, you can call

```
mapMethod(activemap)
```

---

If you want to take the reflection approach instead (which as I said I don't think you should), you can do something along the lines of

```
String methodName = "map" + activemap + "method";
MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod(methodName).invoke(null);
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this to call 2d arrays too, in the same style.
where the arrays are called map1,map2,map3...

Comment: @user2781348 Are your arrays fields of your class or just local variables?

Comment: @user2781348 In that case there is no way to do something similar.

Comment: So if I have a loop that goes through 2d arrays, and I want it to go through the right array depending on what the 'activemap' is I would have to use the switch or if statement?

Comment: @user2781348 That's correct (there are possibly other options like using a `Map` but the idea is similar). This is really much better than using reflection anyway.

Comment: @user2781348 If you're trying to use 2D arrays to do this, your design probably needs reworking.

Answer (score 0):

A switch statement would be slightly easier to read:

```
switch(activemap) {
   case 1:  map1method(); break;
   case 2:  map2method(); break;
}
```

You could use reflection to build the method name up at runtime, but that wouldn't be simpler.      Reflection is a lot of code.

Answer (score 0):

The most effective way to do this is to either create an `enum` to represent the different calls and use the `int` as a lookup for the enum value, or if that's not possible, to use a `switch` statement. You can use reflection to accomplish what you're talking about (look up a method at runtime based on its name), but it's less efficient and more cumbersome than either of those options.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html), It will be something like this:

```
  java.lang.reflect.Method method;

  method = myObject.getClass().getMethod("map+"activemap"+method", param1.class, param2.class, ..);

  method.invoke(object, arg1, arg2,...);
```